# Cannot locate package via terminal ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

i want to install three packages from terminal ubuntu 16.04 lts

when i run command `sudo apt-get install aclocal`

this is the output i get ...

->

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aclocal
```

i also tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but then again unable to install

i also want to install package libtoolize  , pkgconfig aswel i think they are not available in automake .

my os has latest version of automake but its still unable to locate package aclocal.

i am new to ubuntu

thanks

Comment: i tried the solution above mentioned but it also did not worked

Comment: Please state what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: i want to install three packages 1= aclocal , 2= libtoolize , 3= pkgconfig.. i did all the stuff updating apt-get, installing automake but nothing works these packages are unable to locate from terminal for installing

Comment: There is no aclocal *package*.  aclocal is part of automake.  It is already installed.

Comment: ok but when i hit sudo apt-get install aclocal , it says e: unable to lacate package . also with libtoolize and pkgconfig ? what about these 2 remaining?

Comment: Those packages don't exist.

Comment: http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html#.WANQ_BJ97Tf refer to this link , to build linphone android i need these packages , where libtoolize and pkgconfig required . and you say they dont exist ?

Comment: I don't think the author of that article knows what they're talking about. `libtoolize` is really `libtool`, 'pkgconfig` is `pkg-config`, and `actools` has been in `automake` since 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is wrong.  See this comment http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html?showComment=1435013985299#c2524571387228883361.

> I can't install aclocal or libtoolize or pkgconfig on ubuntu 14.04.. can you explain how to do that?
>
> If you are using 32-bit pc than no need to install these packages.

I'd bet that's true if you are using 64 bit as well.  Because they don't exist!

If you want to be sure though, instead try:

```
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Answer (score -1):

check your etc/apt/sources.list file for proper repositories. Use this link https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ for the repositories

Comment: I don't think you are ever going to find a repository providing a package named `aclocal`...